# Create Responsive Image Gallery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive image gallery such as Instagram in mobile. I want to have 3 images in width, without margin from right and left. How can I achieve this?

Here is what I have so far:

```css
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .portfolio-list li {
        width:33.3333%;
        height: 100px;
        border: 3px solid white;
        margin: -3px;
    }

    .portfolio-container,
    .portfolio-list {
        margin-right: 0 ;
        margin-left:0;
        margin-top:10px;
    }

    .portfolio-list {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

portfolio-list {
    list-style: none;
}

.portfolio-list li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.portfolio-list li img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<container class="portfolio-container text-center">
    <ul class="portfolio-list" style="margin:0 auto">
        <li style="margin:0 auto">
            <a href="#"><img src="{{$img['image']}}"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</container>
```

An image of the gallery that I have is:

[image: Image gallery]

Comment: Can you use Bootstrap? It pretty much will take care of all this for you by default

Comment: please tell me Where I Use Bootstrap in my code?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/, then to setup the HTML: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Comment: Bootstrap is quite overkill just for a grid IMO !

Comment: No I Know Bootstrap,I mean is how I can Add bootstrap in my code to have Image gallery such as instagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Added desktop view as well.

- Always put your media querys at the end, otherwise they will get overriden by their following selectors.
- Switched your non-media query `.portofolio-list` to flexbox.
- You are missing a dot in `portfolio-list` where `list-style: none` is.

Basically I added the following:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

To reset browser margins and to prevent boxes from collapsing.

Commented `margin: -3px;` on `.portfolio-list li` to avoid breaking the exact centering.

**https://jsfiddle.net/ujrruyxq/7/**

Images on mobile view:

[image]

Desktop view:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your code sample, it is missing the `</style>` closing tag. also this tag is before the `<html>` one, which is the root tag of a **HTML5** document.

To answer your question, i would use a **responsive CSS grid**, like **[Grillade](https://knacss.com/grillade/index.html)** to solve this problem, firstly because it would be useless to recreate something that already exist, secondly because **you'll need grids almost everywhere** in an application !